# How to open popup window from modal?

Tags: modal-dialog, popup

on this page : https://www.charlesdaudelin.org/www/SallesID.php?Type_No=33&ID_Article=97&SalleID=27
I would like to open the link Cliquez pour voir les photos in the text of the first terminal opens in a new window instead of a tab

I tried this code:
<a href="/www/PopOeuvres.php?locale=fr-CA&Auto_No=397" onclick="window.open(this.href, " ',="" 'resizable="no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no,width=960,height=490');" return="" false;'="" target="_blank">Cliquez pour voir les photos

I would like to open a new 960x490 window instead of a new tab